# Clean-up script tags

Tags: functions, filters, javascript

I want to clean up `<script>` tags generated by WordPress to produce more semantic output for HTML5.

You can already do this for `<style>` tags using this code attached to the `style_loader_tag` filter:

```
//clean up the default WordPress style tags
add_filter('style_loader_tag', 'clean_style_tag');

function clean_style_tag($input) {
    preg_match_all("!<link rel='stylesheet'\s?(id='[^']+')?\s+href='(.*)' type='text/css' media='(.*)' />!", $input, $matches);

    //only display media if it's print
    $media = $matches[3][0] === 'print' ? ' media="print"' : '';                                                                             
    return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . $matches[2][0] . '"' . $media . '>' . "\n";
}
```

But there isn't an equivalent `script_loader_tag` in core yet.  It was [proposed in the past](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13592), but for now we need a workaround.

I've started looking in [`/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php`](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php.source.html) at `function do_item( $handle, $group = false )` around line 79 which holds the script output (specifically `lines 117-120`), but I'm having a bit of trouble finding an appropriate filter that could be used here.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?  From your code, it looks like you want to turn things like `<link rel="stylesheet" id="1234" href="http://site.url/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />` into `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://site.url/style.css" media="screen" />`.  So ... remove attributes like "id" and "type".  Is this accurate?  If so ... why?

Comment: Hi @EAMann - yup, want to clean up the `script` tags as done for the `link` tags - so the output would be `<script src="source_url"></script>`. To answer your question of "why?" it's to produce more semantic output for HTML5 (we don't need those, so they're useless to keep). That WP bug ticket I linked to expresses the same opinion I have about that (which unfortunately isn't in there yet), so looking for a possible workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, then it should already be possible.

The `global $wp_scripts` is an *instance* of the `WP_Scripts` class, which is an *instance* of the `WP_Dependencies` class.

So in theory (not tested), you should be able to do something like this:

```
function alter_script_tags()
{
    echo '<pre>';
        print $GLOBALS['wp_scripts']->print_html;
    echo '</pre>';
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'alter_script_tags', 999999 );
```

This is just a *rough sketch*, but you should get the idea.

Comment: It looks like this was attempted a while ago https://github.com/retlehs/roots/blob/6492fe93187c79a9a8b0bce9fb006fb2f3aa75cc/inc/roots-scripts.php and I remember testing this and it ran into some issues - I'll continue to research on this one. Thanks.

Comment: @Zach Ehm, where do you see `print_html` over there? The code you linked has nothing to do with what I wrote above. What I´m  suggesting is that you intercept the `$print_html` var which holds the output as this is the only possibility to really alter something instead of replacing it (and therefore staying compatible with Plugins and Themes). Btw: If you appreciate it, then I appreciate receiving an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure of WP version compatibility, but taken from the [Soil plugin](https://github.com/roots/soil) module [`clean-up.php`](https://github.com/roots/soil/blob/master/modules/clean-up.php) for [Roots](https://roots.io/). Use in your theme's `functions.php` or similar.

```
function clean_script_tag($input) {
  $input = str_replace("type='text/javascript' ", '', $input);
  return str_replace("'", '"', $input);
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'clean_script_tag');
```